# How to write a wrapper for an arbitrary bash command?

Tags: bash, eval

I want to use the following construction multiple times throughout my script:

```
tries=0
while ! resposta=$(ssh ${nodes[$k]} 'nproc && uptime'); do
    let tries+=1
    if ((tries > max_tries)); then
        printf "Can't connect to %s !!!" "${nodes[$k]}"
        exit 1
    fi
    printf "Failed! Trying again after %d seconds...\n" "$sleep_time"
    sleep $sleep_time
done
```

This code runs the `resposta=$(ssh ${nodes[$k]} 'nproc && uptime')` command multiple times, until it works, or until reaches a maximum number of tries.

However, there are a lot of commands that I would like to wrap up inside a block like the one above. What I'm doing right now is: repeat the whole block everytime I want it, changing the command that makes up the condition of the `while` loop.

This is, of course, boooring and stupid. I would like to avoid `eval`-based solutions, though -- for the even stupider reason that `eval` is evil, besides breaking syntax-highlighting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function that takes the command you would like to run as a quoted argument:

```
function repeat() {
    tries=0
    while ! resposta=$($1); do
        let tries+=1
        if ((tries > max_tries)); then
            printf "Command %s failed" "$1"
            exit 1
        fi
        printf "Failed! Trying again after %d seconds...\n" "$sleep_time"
        sleep $sleep_time
    done
}

repeat "ssh ${nodes[$k]} ''nproc && uptime''"
```

Note that the string is quoted when being passed in, to avoid interpreting it, but not quoted when it is expanded as `$1`, so that the command actually gets called.

Also, note the doubled single quotes. This tells bash to use actual single quote characters in the string passed to the function. Otherwise, the single quotes will be stripped off and you will get the following error from the server:

```
bash: nproc & uptime: command not found
```

Comment: This isn't going to work, because the single quotes become ordinary characters.

Comment: Instead of using `$1`, use `"$@"` with `repeat ssh "${nodes[$k]}" 'nproc && uptime'` , but even then `repeat` won't be able to take arbitrary shell commands, just simple command consisting of a command name and its arguments.

Comment: (Which is not to say this is a bad idea, quite the opposite. It's just not easy to write a complete command wrapper in shell without `eval`.)

Comment: You are right. When I run the following, it fails: `a="ssh jfox@carrsrv10.carrastro.local 'nproc & uptime'"; $a`, just like you said. However, the following behaves just as expected: `a="ssh jfox@carrsrv10.carrastro.local ''nproc & uptime''"; $a`. The problem was that bash was removing the quotes before passing the string. String expansion of commands works fine, you just have to be extra careful with quotes. The answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm falling back to eval, in the end. My motivation to not using eval was not having to deal with escaping the command string. Thanks anyway! I  didn't know this trick with with the double single quotes :)

Comment: I noticed that you're using only one `&` instead of two `&&`. I wonder what it means inside an ssh single-shot. If I run `ssh $node 'cmd1 & cmd2'`, could the ssh session terminate before cmd1 returns?

Comment: @fonini The single `&` appears because I did not escape the double `&&` properly most likely. I am not sure what it would do either...